# Check if Firefox OS is connected to WiFi for privileged apps

Tags: firefox, firefox-os

Is there a way for a privileged Firefox OS app to detect if the WiFi is connected to a network?  I am aware of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Settings but that API is only for certified apps.  All I need to do is detect whether the phone is connected to a network or is not connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [Network Info API](http://www.w3.org/TR/netinfo-api/#idl-def-Connection), which provides you with values about the `bandwidth` (Mb/s estimate) and if the current connection is `metered` (mobile data vs Wifi).

`metered` should be enough to tell if the user is on wifi. There is no need to read the Settings! This API is even accessible for web apps.

Comment: This seems to be the only way to do it.  I tested it with a sim card on an unlimited plan and navigator.mozConnection.metered reported false (which makes sense). I haven't been able to verify that it actually reports true when you're on a limited data plan.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [window.navigator.onLine property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.navigator.onLine)